# Naming of HTML inputs

Tags: angular, naming-conventions

What is the recommended practice in Angular 2 for naming HTML controls: `<input id="abc" name="abc" />`?  `Id` is necessary for things like `<label for="abc">...</label>`, while Angular binding needs `name` to be set.  Any reason why `id` and `name` couldn't/shouldn't always be the same?

How about when you have a component used more than once (e.g. in a list) or a parent and child component have the same `id`/`name` set.  Angular might handle `name` correctly, but how do you prevent collisions with the `id`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are reusing components on a string it is likely that you are using a set of them and can make the id dependent on your `*ngFor`'s `let i = index;` to customize the id element like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <p [id]="i + 'p'">{{item}}<p>
</div>
```

Will yield IDs of '0p', '1p', '2p', etc.

Otherwise you could pass something you want bound to the ID as an input to a component

```
<test-component [myId]="variableFromParent"></test-component>
```

and the test component would have, for instance:

```
<div id="{{myId}}"></div>
```

You can muck around in plunker and see what you like, here's a starting point: http://plnkr.co/edit/UUGtMib8a2wCVP520uD1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the index now, but if the `<p>` is complex and I want to refactor into its own component I wouldn't have direct access to it.  Passing in `myId` like you said could work, maybe even passing in the index and/or some prefix.  I guess that's all doable and would have to be taken care of on a case-by-case basis, but I guess I was hoping there was a built-in way such as `INamingContainer` in ASP.NET.