# Angular 2 how to set correct name when ngModel is inside ngFor in template-driven form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I've got a form with a loop:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let editor of editors; let i = index">
    <code-editor [(ngModel)]="editor.model" name="editors[i]"></code-editor>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I'm facing problems when it comes to setting the name along with the `[(ngModel)]`, since the name is really an index of an array rather than a property name.

Is it possible to do it this way or do I need to create a whole component that incorporates `ControlValueAccessor` that binds all editors to the same model in order to get this to work as intended?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Does `<code-editor>` implement `ControlValueAccessor`?

Comment: Maybe [name]="editors[i]" would help. Or just [name]="editor"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes it does, but the form that has this component also requires a `name` attribute when using `[(ngModel)]` inside the form, since it's template driven.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is with `name`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The name becomes the property which holds the value in the form, but since it's not a property I want to bind to but rather an index it creates problems.

Comment: "creates problems" what problems?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That it binds to a new property rather than the object of the array?..

Comment: Why not `[name]="'editors' + i"`? or `name="editors + {{i}}"`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556487/naming-of-html-inputs/40556884#40556884